# Need example of urdf that opens in gazebo with simple wheel

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Update: If anyone has a mobile robot with a simple revolving wheel described in urdf that runs in gazebo.

Got it: I was able to turn on 3d acceleration to get around blank saveAs dialog. This allows me to toggle between having no gazebo main screen or no saveAs.

The URDF file with proper a joint setting of (I add this line to the joints)

when opened in gazebo replaces the joint axis of
0 10  with
1 9.6e-05 9.6e-05
If I do not add a joint origin then gazebo does not change the axis but does not add
a joint origin and lets it default to the center of the parent.

I can add the origin at the joint in the saved world file so that no translation is done and it works.

=======

Update: Does anyone have an example of a urdf file that opens in gazebo that has a revolving joint.

The sdf file below was generated via gzsdf print on this urdf file.
The sdf file opened in gazebo rolls when a force is applied to joint but not when gazebo is opened with the urdf file. What is wrong with the urdf file. Why does the urdf file joint not align with the wheel axis? The wheel goes out of alignment with the joint axis when a force is applied to the joint in the urdf file under gazebo but not the sdf file.

The image is taken form the full model I am using. The urdf and sdf file demonstrates the issue on a smaller scale.

[C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2013-08-18 11:08:27.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13768387097464708.png)

===================urdf file +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="rrbot">

   <link name='base_link'>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <origin xyz="0 0 .1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box  size=".4 .2 .1"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <visual name='visual'>
        <origin xyz="0 0 .1 " rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box  size=".4 .2 .1"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>

     <inertial>
        <mass value="1e-5" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 .1 " rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
     </inertial>
  </link> 


    
  <link name="left_wheel">
    <collision name="collision">
      <origin xyz="0.2 0.13 0.1" rpy="0 1.5707 1.5707"/>
      <geometry>
         <cylinder  length="0.05" radius="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual">
      <origin xyz="0.2 0.13 0.1" rpy="0 1.5707 1.5707"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder  length="0.05" radius="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1e-5" />
      <origin xyz="0.2 0.13 0.1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
    </inertial>
  </link>
 
 
  <joint type="revolute" name="joint1">
    <!-- origin taken from generated pose for joint , form the file that was created by gzsdf print -->
    <origin xyz="0.2 0.13 0.1" rpy="-1.56451e-13 1.5707 1.5707"/>
    <child link="left_wheel">left_wheel</child>
    <parent link="base_link">base_link</parent>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="30" velocity="1.0"  lower="-100" upper="100" />
  </joint>



</robot>



======================= SDF generated file +++++++++++++++++++++++++++

<sdf version='1.4'>
  <model name='rrbot'>
    <link name='base_link'>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 0.1 0 -0 0</pose>
        <mass>1e-05</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>1e-06</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>1e-06</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>1e-06</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <collision name='base_link_collision'>
        <pose>0 0 0.1 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.4 0.2 0.1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name='base_link_visual'>
        <pose>0 0 0.1 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.4 0.2 0.1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <velocity_decay>
        <linear>0</linear>
        <angular>0</angular>
      </velocity_decay>
    </link>
    <link name='left_wheel'>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0.2 0.13 0.1 0 -0 0</pose>
        <mass>1e-05</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>1e-06</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>1e-06</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>1e-06</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <collision name='left_wheel_collision'>
        <pose>0.2 0.13 0.1 -1.56451e-13 1.5707 1.5707</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <length>0.05</length>
            <radius>0.1</radius>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name='left_wheel_visual'>
        <pose>0.2 0.13 0.1 -1.56451e-13 1.5707 1.5707</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <length>0.05</length>
            <radius>0.1</radius>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <velocity_decay>
        <linear>0</linear>
        <angular>0</angular>
      </velocity_decay>
    </link>
    <joint name='joint1' type='revolute'>
      <pose>0.2 0.13 0.1 -1.56451e-13 1.5707 1.5707</pose>
      <child>left_wheel</child>
      <parent>base_link</parent>
      <axis>
        <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
        <limit>
          <lower>-100</lower>
          <upper>100</upper>
          <effort>30</effort>
          <velocity>1</velocity>
        </limit>
        <dynamics/>
      </axis>
    </joint>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4164/need-example-of-urdf-that-opens-in-gazebo-with-simple-wheel/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have extracted the robot model out from a save world and made it its own model in .gazebo/models and now keep a separate urdf. I have been unable to get urdf and gazebo to work together otherwise.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) with karma: 107 on 2013-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0